# Listbox DisplayMember from nested object VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a class called ComponentTransactionPair, it houses two objects called m_Component and m_Transaction, there is a public property

```
Protected m_componentTransactionPair As List(Of ComponentTransactionPair)
```

In trying to hook this to a ListBox I am using the code below

```
lstbCurrentTransactions.DataSource = m_componentTransactionPair
m_currentOptionsLoaded = True
lstbCurrentTransactions.DisplayMember = "m_Transaction.Description"
```

The DisplayMember is not working properly for me in doing this and i'm pretty sure it's displaying the type rather than the Description property within the Transaction.

Is it even possible to use a nested object's property to get this category here because everything I've seen does not use a nested object.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this looks like WinForms, not WPF. `DataSource` and `DisplayMemeber` are both properties of the WinForms [`ListControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol).

Comment: Thats probably correct, still learning this and got the two confused.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by just adding another property to the class and took it from the value I needed. Worked perfectly afterwards. If there's a less hacky solution i'd be interested to hear it though.